# range between the min and max value

Tags: java

Create a NumberInTheRange application that prompts the user for two numbers.
The first number is a min value and the second is a max value. Prompter then prompts the user for a number between the min and max numbers entered. The user should be continually prompted until a number within the range is entered. Be sure to include the min and max numbers in the prompt.

I wrote a code allowing the users to write the two min and max values. However, I am wondering what code should I write in order to fulfill the conditions above. I am thinking about using loops and it would be very helpful if you guys correct me and give some instructions on how to process these.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NumberinTheRange {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Type two numbers:");
        int n1=scan.nextInt();
        int n2=scan.nextInt();  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `do...while` loop.

```
int num;
do {
   System.out.println("Enter a number between " + n1 + " and " + n2 + ":");
   num = scan.nextInt();
} while(num < n1 || num > n2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Now, you need to put a condition to loop-back if the input is not in the range. You can use a `do-while` loop for the same. You can do it with any other loop but using a `do-while` loop guarantees that its body will be executed at least once.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Type two numbers: ");
        int min = scan.nextInt();
        int max = scan.nextInt();
        int n;
        do {
            System.out.print("Enter a number in the range of " + min + "-" + max + ": ");
            n = scan.nextInt();
        } while (n < min || n > max);
        System.out.println("Your number is: " + n);
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
Type two numbers: 10 20
Enter a number in the range of 10-20: 34
Enter a number in the range of 10-20: 5
Enter a number in the range of 10-20: 15
Your number is: 15
```